# Continuously getting error in spark-submit command

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am uncertain whether this is a bug, however I am getting the error below when running on a cluster and have no idea what is causing it, or where to look for more information.
Any help is appreciated. Others appear to experience the same issue, but I have not found any solutions online.

Please note that this only happens with certain code and is repeatable, all my other spark jobs work fine.

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
  Task 93 in stage 6.4 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 93.3 in stage 6.4 (TID 29684, ip-172-16-7-203.ec2.internal, executor 895):
  java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_17_piece0 of broadcast_17
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1333)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Could you explain what your Spark code is supposed to do? Maybe provide (a subset of) the code?

Comment: spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --conf spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2 --conf spark.akka.frameSize=512 --executor-memory 21g --executor-cores 3 --num-executors 300 --conf spark.cleaner.ttl=60 --conf spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=600 --conf spark.yarn.executfor.failuresValidityInterval=2h --driver-memory=32g --conf spark.network.timeout=10000001 --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1720

Comment: --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xss300m -Dhadoop.tmp.dir=/mnt/var/hadoop' --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss300m -Dhadoop.tmp.dir=/mnt/var/hadoop' --conf spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.cleanup.skipped=true

Comment: Can you check in your code if your SparkContext is perhaps initialized more than once? 
This error could be related to a SparkContext stopping?

Comment: Look for the broadcast timeout configuration.

Comment: Can you please add the code to your Class that you are calling?

Comment: @lamanus can you please specify the property name.

Comment: @Anish i have already the code to my class.

Comment: @Fudgy How to check SparkContext is perhaps initialized more than once

Comment: @Lamanus I am not using any broadcast join in my code.

Comment: Can you add the Spark code that is producing this error. (not just the spark-submit command)